# Prevent sending emails from root@$hostname...

Tags: php, html, email

Every email which is send by users by submitting contact form is being sent by default account, which look like this:-
root@myserver_hostname.com
I need help on how to prevent sending emails like that ..?

Thank you

Comment: please post your code to see how you used header fields.

Comment: Put a different `From: username@domain` in the `$headers` argument to `mail()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default email.

Just set the email you want in the header.

**Example:**

```
$from = 'Your Site Name <other_email@example.com>';

$to = 'user_email@example.com';

$subject = 'Subject';
$message = 'Your message';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;

// Is HTML?
// $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . PHP_EOL;

// The magic
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . PHP_EOL;

$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got the break through, I was using the admin's email stored in wp-admin.
So I changed that email to something else and then the root username was gone.

Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: @shadow In my opinion, this is not just a "thank you" comment, but an answer to the question, too, since it resolves the problem.